# Why do I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when re-opening an NSWindow after closing it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, exc-bad-access, nswindow

I'm calling the following code after a double-click event in order to open a small window at the mouse position.
It works fine, and will re-appear at the new position every time, but if I manually close the window first, I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

```
win =  [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                 styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask)
                                 backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                 defer:false];
        [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```

and the window is declared in the interface of the view which calls the code above

```
 @interface myView : NSView
{
    NSWindow *win;
}
```

If it's relevant, I'm using ARC, and in the debugger I can see that `win` is not nil after closing and then just before trying trying to re-create it, though its contentView has become nil.

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: This may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374252/exc-bad-access-when-i-close-my-window-which-is-also-my-applications-delegate

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately there's a lot of other factors in their case that don't apply to my simple case, and I couldn't find anything to try.

Comment: What if you programmatically close it?

Comment: I have the same problem. You can fix this the crash by doing [win setReleasedWhenClose:false]; but in my case I want to release it and recreate it so it doesn't really fix the problem…

Comment: Thanks. Seems odd that the default behaviour is the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in Swift. To fix it, as per Vin's comment, I used `window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false`. This prevents the window from being released on close, allowing you to reopen it without any sort of error.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-isreleasedwhenclosed